# Help: Using if-else on two switch state

Tags: programming, hardware, switch

## Problem

I'm stuck on triggering different switch. I'll explain what each of  my switch should do. Output of this setup : No output from `relayPin`

`mainPin`

- Main power of the switch to control `relayPin` — keeps on/off
- Override `reedPin` state
- Let `SecondState`

`reedPin`

- Secondary power switch to control `relayPin` — depends on `mainPin` on/off state
- Overridden by `mainPin`
- Let `FirstState`

*another explanation in comment

Is it caused by coding or hardware? Pardon my ignorance, it is my beginner code. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

## Code

```
const int reedPin = 8; // Reed Switch
const int mainPin = 9; // Main Switch
const int relayPin = 6; // Relay

int FirstState = 0;
int SecondState = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(reedPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(mainPin, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
    FirstState = digitalRead(reedPin);
    SecondState = digitalRead(mainPin);
    if (FirstState == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
    }
    else if (SecondState == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Only `else if (SecondState == HIGH) {` works in output.

## Schematics

[image]

Comment: 1. Your problem statement is very hard to understand. A pair of switches can be in four different states (off/off, off/on, on/off, on/on): please clearly state what the program should do in _each_ of these four cases. 2. Do _not_ connect the relay directly to the Arduino: first search the Web for “connect relay to Arduino”, then use a suitable transistor.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I'm using relay alone on schematics because I'm using module instead. There is 2 switch, first one acts like normal and override second switch which are reed switch. IF first one is on, then second one has a function to on/off. IF the first one is off, then second one has NO function

Comment: Only you know what “_first one acts like normal and override second switch_” means. Again, please, tell us what the Arduino should do in each of the four possible situations. If you are unable to tell us what your Arduino should do, then you will never be able to program it to do what you want.

Comment: Alright, first switch `SW1` is main switch - referred as `firstState` in code.
when this is off, `U1` (referred as `secondState` in code) has no function

What `U1` does is simple on/off (reed switch).
What `SW1` does enables `U1` function

Sorry for confusion.

Comment: The first one "enables" the second one ? You are missing a pinMode(switchMain, INPUT). Please use 'relayPin' instead of 'relaySwitch'. Use consistant names for everything. Please use always the same name for the first one, second one, and so on. Both in your sketch and in your explanation. Update your question and the sketch as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a truth table and look at it from there.  From your words, it is confusing.  From your code it looks like this:

```
mainPin    reedPin   relayPin
HIGH        LOW      LOW
HIGH        HIGH     LOW
LOW         LOW      HIGH
LOW         HIGH     HIGH
```

So:

```
void loop() {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, !digitalRead(mainPin));
}
```

If you want:

```
mainPin    reedPin   relayPin
HIGH        LOW      LOW
HIGH        HIGH     LOW
LOW         LOW      HIGH
LOW         HIGH     LOW
```

then:

```
void loop() {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, !(digitalRead(mainPin) || digitalRead(reedPin)));
}
```